# crontab is not execute the script for recording

Tags: bash, cron

I wish to run my bash file called server1.sh by crontab at the limited times.
The commands i type to run it as below:

```
0 10-17 19 7 * home/Documents/recording/server1.sh
```

I saved and exit after typing above command.

then I type under same directory as below:

```
sudo chmod +x server1.sh

sudo chmod +x crontab
```

Then I wait and see whether to know the commands work or not.
it didnt work.

Please advice and correct me for the right.

Comment: The path is wrong if you mean your Home directory. It must be soemting like `/home/user_name/Documents...`.

Comment: thanks. 
sorry, I left to type. in my actual command, it is written as u told.
/home/sensen/Documents/recording/server1.sh

Comment: Why did you run `sudo chmod +x crontab`?

Answer (score 2):

In order to add entries to `crontab` you should execute the following command:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

> **man crontab**
>
> The -e option is used to edit the  current  crontab

The crontab should hold `/` before `home`

```
0 10-17 19 7 * /home/sensen/Documents/recording/server1.sh
```

Note: I'm not sure why did you execute:

```
sudo chmod +x crontab
```

Comment: I don't think that `Documents` are in `/home`. ;-)

Comment: thank you. the server is cctv ip cameras server.I executed for cctv recording . no need to run "sudo chmod +x server1.sh"?

Comment: @Sithu - did you edit `crontab` using `sudo crontab -e` as described in my answer?